# Allow any subset of specified array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Can I specify an array as a type in Typescript and then any subset of this array is allowed to be passed?

E.g.

```
type Actions = ['view', 'share', 'delete']

const concatActions = (actions: Actions) => actions.join();

concatActions(['view', 'delete']) // Works
concatActions(['share']) // Works
concatActions(['view', 'some_other_action']) // Throws type error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
type Action = 'view' | 'share' | 'delete'
type Actions = Action[]
```

Comment: Is there a way also to disallow duplicates? so that `['share', 'view', 'share']` is not allowed.

Comment: I don't think so, not TypeScript natively at least. The solution would be to prevent dupes in `concatActions`. You can create a new SO question and send it to me if you wonder how to do that. Let's stay on topic :)